# Share To Teams Error "Could not load content for https://local.teams.office.com/sourcemaps/../unhashed-assets/launcher.js.map"

Tags: microsoft-teams

We are trying to add "Share To Teams" button to our web application which is an angular app.

but while adding script, it gives an error as

> Could not load content for
> https://local.teams.office.com/sourcemaps/../unhashed-assets/launcher.js.map:
> Connection error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

And the button does not display.

```
 <a class="teams-share-button" data-href="someurl"></a>
```

Script rendering function in typescript

```
 private appendShareToTeamsScript(): void{
        //Add Share to Teams script to the page 
        var script   = document.createElement("script");
        script.type  = "text/javascript";
        script.src   = "https://teams.microsoft.com/share/launcher.js";
        document.body.appendChild(script);
      }
```

Comment: What happens if you just add the script reference directly, like:
<script src="https://teams.microsoft.com/share/launcher.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Incidentally, an error loading the ".map" file shouldn't really be a blocker, but obviously the button not loading is more of an issue

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow It gives the same error if we add reference directly in html.

Comment: Try adding the text  <a class="teams-share-button" data-href="someurl">some text here</a>

Comment: @VaraPrasad-MSFT it just downloads the file then

Answer (score 2):

To load external JavaScript on component use ngOnInit() to append the libraries.

I have tried the below code snippet and worked for me.

Add below anchor tag in home.component.html

```
   <a class="teams-share-button" data-href="yor url" data-icon-px-size="64"></a>
```

add below code snippet in home.component.ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

      @Component({
      selector: 'app-home',
      templateUrl: './home.component.html',
    })

    export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
     title = 'app';

      ngOnInit() {
        this.loadScript('https://teams.microsoft.com/share/launcher.js');
     }
  
     public loadScript(url: string) {
     const body = <HTMLDivElement> document.body;
     var script = document.createElement('script');   
     script.src = url;
     body.appendChild(script);
     }
   }
```

Comment: Still the same issue and Got 2 warnings on console.

1. Share To Microsoft Teams:  No Share To Microsoft Teams Element found

2. DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for https://local.teams.office.com/sourcemaps/../unhashed-assets/launcher.js.map: Connection error: net::ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID